# Custom remote video thumbnail

Tags: 8, entities, media

I'm using the media entity from Drupal core together with the media library, to handle media on my site.

I have `Remote Video` and `Image with crop` media types. I'm using the `crop` and `image_widget_crop` modules to manually crop images on my site.

Remote video supports `YouTube` and `Vimeo`.

Right now the thumbnail is automatically generated, but I want to be able to upload a custom thumbnail. If no custom thumbnail is provided, it will just use the auto generated one.

I found [this guide](https://stevepolito.design/blog/customize-video-thumbnail-drupal/), but it is for Drupal 7.

Has anyone done something similar to this in Drupal 8?

Comment: Is this the thumbnail used in the media library module? As I'd guess what you could do is add a new image field to the remote video media type. Then just change go into "manage display" and change the media library display to show that instead of the thumbnail. You could do that for any other display e.e.g the default too

Comment: Yes, the only problem is that it has to fallback to the auto generated thumbnail if a custom thumbnail has not been uploaded.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I forgot about that. You could potentially create a new FieldFormatter that was essentially a copy of the standard Image one (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21image%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldFormatter%21ImageFormatter.php/class/ImageFormatter/8.2.x)  but it would check for the custom image by using $items->getParent() to get the parent entity with all its fields

Comment: @Leigh Thanks for the tip I actually found a solution myself :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding an image field on the remote video media entity and then altering the media entity on presave, like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_presave().
 */
function MY_MODULE_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'media' && isset($entity->field_media_image->entity)) {
    $entity->thumbnail->target_id = $entity->field_media_image->target_id;
  }
}
```

The image field is called `field_media_image`.

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm. THX!

Comment: You can use the more specific `MY_MODULE_media_presave` hook, and you don't have to check the entity type.